# Writing sleep data to Google Fit from a Flutter App

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, google-fit

I am trying to write sleep data which I get from a self-made Flutter app to Google Fit. This app simply outputs a boolean which says "sleep activity" yes/no for a certain amount of time. Is there a way to convert such a simple boolean to a Google Fit data type and send it to Google Fit/connect with Google Fit? I only found Health and fit_kit packages on pub.dev. It seems to me that both packages can only read data from Google Fit but can not write data from a Flutter app to Google Fit.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What exactly does "yes/no" mean in the context of sleep activity? [Google Fit's sleep data](https://developers.google.com/fit/scenarios/write-sleep-data) isn't simply yes or no.

Comment: This would correspond to the example without granularity here. So I simply want to send either a String SLEEP or AWAKE.